# Ruby 'require' errors with Selenium webdriver script

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to execute a script to test some user credentials, and I keep getting errors relating to 'require'. The script takes a csv of usernames and passwords, logs them into a site, and groups them into pass/fail lists.

I confess I didn't write the script- it was provided to us by an outside coder. I've taken a few CS101 classes, and can parse what it's doing and modify it for different domains and credential files, but I'm a total ruby beginner.

=========================

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'
require 'rubygems'
require 'csv'

pass_file = File.open('pass.txt', 'w')
fail_file = File.open('fail.txt', 'w')
in_file = File.open('test credentials.csv', 'r')

pass_file.puts "xxxxxx"
fail_file.puts "xxxxxx"

CSV.foreach(in_file, :col_sep => ',') do |row|
  driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
  driver.get 'https://www.xxxxxx.com/'

  driver.find_element(:id => 'UserNameEntry').send_keys row[0]
  driver.find_element(:id => 'UserPasswordEntry').send_keys row[1]
  driver.find_element(:id => 'xxxxxxlNameEntry').clear
  driver.find_element(:id => 'xxxxxxNameEntry').send_keys "xxxxxx"
  driver.find_element(:xpath => '//*[@id="cmdLoginButton"]/span').click
  driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
  if driver.title == "Welcome!"
    pass_file.puts row[0]
  elsif driver.title == "Login Unsuccessful"
    fail_file.puts row[0]
  end
  driver.quit
end
```

==================

When I run it, at first I was getting "`require': no such file to load -- selenium-webdriver (LoadError)
    from xxxxx.rb:1

Then I read on a forum that the requirement for gems should come first. After putting require 'rubygems' before require 'selenium-webdriver', now I get this error:

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/csv.rb:308:in `initialize': can't convert File into String (TypeError)
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/csv.rb:308:in`open'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/csv.rb:308:in `open_reader'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/csv.rb:94:in`foreach'

I'm feeling so confused...any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the gems before you can require them.  For example, the selenium-webdriver gem can be found here
[Selenium WebDriver](http://rubygems.org/gems/selenium-webdriver)

You run `gem install selenium-webdriver` in a terminal program.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove space from csv file name, for example:

```
in_file = File.open('test_credentials.csv', 'r')
```

As I can see from the stacktrace, error occurs when reading csv file.

Answer (score 0):

1. If there is not space between `test credentials.csv` then remove that. Check that there is _ present or not
2. If there is a space between `test credentials.csv` then write file name in your code as follows `in_file = File.open("test\ credentials.csv", 'r')`

Answer (score 0):

If you use Bundler, add `require bundler/setup` at the top.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

gem update --system