# Selenium Data Driven Test in Ruby, Compare CSV to existing data, takers?

Tags: ruby, csv

I'm new to ruby! 
I'm trying to automate the test for this task. It's simple:

I've a data content (workgroup member list) within a web application 
And each of the workgroups have their associated CSV file export.
I'm trying to compare the list in CSV file to the web application data.

How do I make this happen in Selenium using Ruby? Please write an example to get me started so I can keep working on it!
Thank you very much!!

Comment: You can try this example as shown in the question [Example for csv read](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12165382/ruby-require-errors-with-selenium-webdriver-script)